# Can a .dockeringore file include a volume folder?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

Imagine a project folder like this:

- project_folder

  - source_code_folder_1
  - docker_volume_folder
  - source_code_file_1
  - Dockerfile
  - docker-compose.yml
  - .dockerignore

Now, if

- the `Dockerfile` contains an instruction `ADD . /code/`, and
- if the `docker-compose.yml` file configures a service that uses the `docker_volume_folder` in its volume mapping,

can I then add the `docker_volume_folder` in the `.dockerignore` file, to prevent that the volume folder is copied to the docker container by the `ADD . /code/` instruction in the dockerfile?

I think adding the docker volume folder to the docker container is not only useless, maybe it's even dangerous. However, I want to avoid that Docker Compose does not want to create the volume, since it is mentioned in the `.dockerignore` file.

I can't find information about volumes in the dockerignore [in the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include the directory in your .dockerignore file, that only affects the build, not the later volume mounts.

The only reason you may want to include the directory inside your image is if you want named volumes to be initialized with the contents of the image. If you only use host volumes, this will not be an issue.