# Ignoring every `node_modules` in a docker volume

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to ignore every `node_modules` in every workspaces / sub folders.

The fact is : it is impossible to (really) ignore a folder by its name in a volume.

So there was this trick :

```
volumes:
  - ./:/app
  - /app/node_modules
```

It works well for apps that have one single `node_modules`. But what if there is multiple one like in the bellow directory tree ?

```
project
|   node_modules/
|   docker-compose.yml
|   Dockerfile
|
└─── workspaces/
|   └─── client/
|       |   node_modules/
|   |
|   └─── server/
|       |   node_modules/
```

Do I need really need to mount every `node_modules` as a volume in my `docker-compose.yml` ?

```
volumes:
  - ./:/app
  - /app/node_modules
  - /app/workspaces/client/node_modules
  - /app/workspaces/server/node_modules
```

Or is there another better way ?

Comment: I think you can add `node_modules` into  `dockerignore` file

Comment: @DominikMatis According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50745824/8990411) you cannot ignore what's inside a volume, because is it shared to the container after the build. As I said there's a solution but it isn't really viable when there is a lot of `node_modules` to ignore.

Comment: I'm always thinking about `**/node_modules` but I'm on mobile so can't test it sorry

Comment: Dominik's solution may work, c.f. this reply: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56511833/1006854

Comment: @Mehdi Maybe I am missing something but, if there is a file (let's call it `file.txt`) in one of the host's `node_modules` folder, it should works when the container is being build but right after when the container is started, the volume will share the host's `node_modules` to the container with the `file.txt` in it. Try it, then run a an `ls` with `docker exec` and you will see the file. But again, maybe I am missing something.

Comment: There is a feature request opened [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6997)

Answer (score 0):

rewrite as "*node_modules"
hopefully it helps

Comment: Where ? As a volume ?

Comment: use this ( - ./:*node_modules)

Comment: `ERROR: for app  Cannot create container for service app: invalid volume spec "*node_modules": invalid volume specification: '*node_modules': invalid mount config for type "volume": invalid mount path: '*node_modules' mount path must be absolute`